# Pagination $_POST loading on one page?

Tags: php, pagination

My problem is to get the pagination to work correctly.

Since I have a $page = $POST_["zain"] for receiving the records there is a problem with the pagination that it shows only result of first page.

 
Here is my code

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="zain.php" method="post">
    Topic: <input type="text" name="topic"><br />
    <br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
    Attendance: <input type="text" name="attendance"><br />
    <br />
    <input type="reset" name="reset">
    <input type="submit" id = "go" name="submit" value="Go">
    </form>

    <?php

    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'zz224466';
    $db = 'Zain';

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $password, $db);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "";

        mysqli_select_db($conn, "zain");
        //$sql = "CREATE TABLE Lectures(Topic varchar(20), Name varchar(20), Attendence int)";
    $sqli = "INSERT INTO lectures(Topic , Name , Attendence) VALUES('$_POST[topic]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[attendance]')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);


    ////////////////////////// For print DATABASE on the screen using PAGINATION ////////////////////////////////////////

            mysqli_select_db($conn, "zain");
            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            if($page=="" || $page=="1")
            {
                $page1 = 0;
            }
    else
    {
        $page1 = ($page*5)-5;
    }
```

}
                $dataBase = "SELECT * FROM lectures limit $page1,5";

```
            $print = mysqli_query($conn, $dataBase);


            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($print))
            {
                echo $record['Topic'];
                echo "</br>";
            }



    $selectDatabase = "SELECT * FROM lectures";
     $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $selectDatabase);
    $countRow = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
    $a = $countRow/5;
    $a = ceil($a);
    echo "<br>" . $a;
    echo "</br> </br>";
    for($b=1; $b<=$a; $b++)
    {
        ?><a href ="zain.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>" style="text-decoration: none"><?php echo $b . " ";?></a><?php
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you will also need that `$POST_["zain"]` variable in the next pages too.  better use `$_GET` variables

Comment: Should I create new Pages?

Comment: No! You just need to use  $page = $_GET["zain"]; instead of  $page = $_POST["zain"];

Comment: what is $page = $_POST["zain"];?// where you passing it.and how you can retrieve it

Comment: I have tried.. It doesnot work

Comment: Error: `Notice: Undefined index: zain in C:\xampp\htdocs\zain.php on line 43`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the top of your page.

```
$zain = !empty($_POST["zain"])?$_POST["zain"]:(!empty($_GET["zain"])?$_GET["zain"]:false);
if(!$zain) die("zain is empty");
```

then replace all other `$_POST["zain"]` to `$zain`

On the link part

```
for($b=1; $b<=$a; $b++)
{
    ?><a href ="zain.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>&zain=<?php echo $zain;?>" style="text-decoration: none"><?php echo $b . " ";?></a><?php
}
```

Comment: It has only problem with `page` inside GET if(isset($_GET['page'])). Error is `Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\zain.php` Can you please fix this